# Light beams reflecting from parabola

Tags: plotting, physics, geometry

How can we show the paths of three light beams in Mathematica which bounce back after hitting the parabola, in a single plot?
Suppose we have the following code

```
Clear[f, x]; 
f[x_] = x^2/8; 
{x[t_], y[t_]} = {t, f[t]}; 
parabola = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thickness[0.01]}}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];

Clear[beam]; 
beam[t_] := Vector[{x[t], y[t]} - {x[t], 6}, Tail -> {x[t], 6}, VectorColor -> Red]; 
Show[parabola, beam[1], beam[2], beam[3], PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run. It is unclear what `Vector` is because it isn't a built-in function. Please also define `parabola`.

Comment: Now I think it would work.

Comment: see [Wolfram Demonstrations >> Reflection in a Parabolic Mirror](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ReflectionInAParabolicMirror/)

Comment: In that Demonstration, all three rays emerge from a single source. Here I have three different sources.

Comment: The demonstrations are often "cute" and show off the skill of the person who created the demonstration to display a graphical result, but they often do not include material in a form that is easy to take and use for other purposes. At best it sometimes seem they let you know something is possible. But to incorporate the ideas into another project seems to often require reverse engineering to try to recover the thought process used so that you can implement a solution to a different problem. If the demonstrations were encouraged to include usable code at the bottom they might be more useful.

Comment: The linked demonstration has fairly straightforward code. I would say that demos in general are not meant, or at least required, to be instructive programming examples, and often aren't (e.g., comments aren't allowed in published code, for instance). The main problem with it is that the code solves three special cases of the reflection problem and not the general problem. However, it does give an answer to the main question of how to show the paths, namely, `Line[{p1, p2, p3}]`, where `p1` is the starting point, `p2` the reflection point, and `p3` the end point.

Answer (score 3):

From point **from** with direction **direction** onto the parabola **f**
The incident beam is in blue, the reflected in green and the normal is dashed red.

```
Clear[beam];
beam[from_, direction_, parabola_] := Module[{lambda, p, x, y, solx, dir = direction/Norm[direction], normal, vref}, 
solx = Solve[dir[[1]] parabola[x] == from[[2]] dir[[1]] + (x - from[[1]]) dir[[2]], x]; 
If[Abs[dir[[1]]] > 0.00001,
  lambda = Max[(x - from[[1]])/dir[[1]] /. solx], 
  lambda = Max[(parabola[x] - from[[2]])/dir[[2]] /. solx]
]; 
x = from[[1]] + lambda dir[[1]];
normal = {-D[parabola[y], y], 1} /. {y -> x};
normal = normal/Norm[normal];
vref = 2 normal + dir;
vref = vref/Norm[vref];
Return[{{x, parabola[x]}, vref, normal, lambda}]
]


f[x_] = x^2/8;
{x[t_], y[t_]} = {t, f[t]};
gr0 = ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, -4, 4}, PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thickness[0.02]}}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];

from = {1, 8};
direction = {1, -4};
parabola = f;
{int, vref, normal, lambda} = beam[from, direction, f]
gr1 = ParametricPlot[from + mu direction/Norm[direction], {mu, 0, lambda}, PlotStyle -> Blue];
gr2 = ParametricPlot[int + mu vref, {mu, 0, lambda}, PlotStyle -> Green];
gr3 = ParametricPlot[int + mu normal, {mu, 0, lambda}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Dashed}];
Show[gr1, gr2, gr3, gr0, PlotRange -> {{-4, 4}, {0, 8}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted Cesareo's answer, but I thought demonstrating the reflection property of a parabola deserves a cute toy for the purpose:

```
DynamicModule[{foc = {0, 2}, source = {-2, 2}, target = {2, 1/2}}, 
              Dynamic[Show[Plot[With[{a = Last[foc]}, (x^2)/(4 a)], {x, -6, 6}, 
                                AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {0, 6}], 
                           Graphics[{{Directive[Arrowheads[Small], AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}], 
                                                Magenta], 
                                      Dynamic[Arrow[{source, target}], 
                                              TrackedSymbols :> {source, target}], 
                                      Dynamic[Arrow[{target, 
                                                     target + Norm[source - target]
                                                     Normalize[source - target - 
                                                               2 Projection[source - target,
                                                                            {2 Last[foc],
                                                                             First[target]}]]}]]},
                                     {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[6], Blue], 
                                      Dynamic[Point[source], TrackedSymbols :> {source}], 
                                      Locator[Dynamic[source, TrackedSymbols :> {source}], 
                                              Appearance -> None]},
                                     {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[6], Blue], 
                                      Dynamic[Point[target], TrackedSymbols :> {target}], 
                                      Locator[Dynamic[target,
                                              (target = With[{u = First[#]},
                                                             {u, (u^2)/(4 Last[foc])}];) &, 
                                                      TrackedSymbols :> {foc, target}], 
                                                      Appearance -> None]},
                                     {Directive[AbsolutePointSize[8], Red], 
                                      Dynamic[Point[foc], TrackedSymbols :> {foc}], 
                                      Locator[Dynamic[foc, (foc = {0, Max[0, Last[#]]}; 
                                              target = With[{u = First[target]},
                                                            {u, (u^2)/(4 Last[foc])}];) &, 
                                                      TrackedSymbols :> {foc, target}],
                                                      Appearance -> None]}}], 
                                    Method -> {"AxesInFront" -> False}]]]
```

[image: reflection on a parabola]

Here, you can adjust the position of the red dot (the *focus*) to change the parabola, and the two blue dots define the ray to be reflected by the parabola.

The key formula here relies on the proper application of `Projection[]` for computing the position of the reflected ray. Here is a simpler demonstration of the formula:

```
With[{source = {-2, 1}/3, target = AngleVector[π/6]/4, direction = AngleVector[π/6]}, 
     Graphics[{{AbsoluteThickness[4], InfiniteLine[{0, 0}, direction]},
               {AbsoluteDashing[{5, 5}], InfiniteLine[target, Cross[direction]]},
               Arrow[{source, target}], 
               Arrow[{target, target + Norm[source - target]
                                       Normalize[source - target -
                                                 2 Projection[source - target,
                                                              direction]]}]}, 
              PlotRange -> 1]]
```

[image: reflection over a line]

Going back to the parabola, I encourage you, the reader, to look at what happens in the following two situations:

1. The movable arrow is oriented vertically
2. The movable arrow passes through the red dot

Answer (score 0):

This works, but it's not clear if you want also handle the case where beams are not parallel to y-axis.

````
Clear[f, parabola, beam];
f[x_] = x^2/8;
parabola = 
  Plot[f[t], {t, -4, 4}, 
   PlotStyle -> {{Blue, Thickness[0.01]}}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}];
beam[x_] := Module[{yc = f[x], m = RotationMatrix[2 ArcTan[f'[x]]]},
   {Line[{{x, 6}, {x, yc}}], Line[{{x, yc}, {x, yc} + m.{0, 6}}]}
   ];
Show[parabola, Table[Graphics[beam[i]], {i, 1, 2, 0.5}], 
 PlotRange -> All]```
````